# Select Max Records on UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, union-all

I have the following which brings me back 3 sets of results correctly

```
SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
FROM            dbo.tblThree
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
ORDER BY rID DESC

SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
FROM            dbo.tblTwo
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
ORDER BY rID DESC

SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
FROM            dbo.tblOne
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
ORDER BY rID DESC
```

Adding a `UNION ALL` between them fails because of the `ORDER BY` statements. However if I get rid of them, the it fails because it doesn't get the latest record.

Is there a simpler solution to this? What I want is a single SQL statement to output the 3 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to get your desired output:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT        rid,score, weight, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rID DESC) AS rn
    FROM            dbo.tblThree
    WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT        rid,score, weight, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rID DESC) AS rn
    FROM            dbo.tblTwo
    WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT        rid,score, weight, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rID DESC) AS rn
    FROM            dbo.tblOne
    WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
)
SELECT *
FROM    data 
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Works but I'm amazed it has to be such a complex query for something, at least to me, is a relatively easy piece of work

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
select * from ( select top (1) rid, score, weight
                from dbo.tblThree
                where caseNo = '111111111'
                order by rid desc) t1
union all
select * from ( select top (1) rid, score, weight
                from dbo.tblTwo
                where caseNo = '111111111'
                order by rid desc) t2
union all
select * from ( select top (1) rid, score, weight
                from dbo.tblOne
                where caseNo = '111111111' 
                order by rid desc) t3
```

Comment: Sorry no, brings back the first record for each table and not the last

Comment: this will perform faster than the chosen answer (tested) and has a more simple execution plan

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select rID,score, weight from 
(SELECT        TOP (1) rID,score, weight,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by rID) as a
FROM            dbo.tblThree
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
UNION ALL
SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by rID) as a
FROM            dbo.tblTwo
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
UNION ALL
SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by rID) as a
FROM            dbo.tblOne
WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111'))t
```

Comment: No column name was specified for column 4 of 't'.

Comment: Not required so not specify

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE1 as
(
  SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
  FROM            dbo.tblThree
  WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
  ORDER BY rID DESC
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
  FROM            dbo.tblTwo
  WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
  ORDER BY rID DESC
), CTE3 as
(
  SELECT        TOP (1) rid,score, weight
  FROM            dbo.tblOne
  WHERE        (caseNo = '111111111')
  ORDER BY rID DESC
)
SELECT
  rid,score, weight 
FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  rid,score, weight 
FROM CTE2
UNION ALL
SELECT
  rid,score, weight 
FROM CTE3
```